# Docker error "Could not attach to network <name>: context deadline exceeded."

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to run a container that connects to an overlay network in my docker swarm, but I get the following error:

```
$ docker run --rm --network mystack_default alpine
docker: Error response from daemon: Could not attach to network mystack_default : context deadline exceeded.
```

The error `context deadline exceeded` is a go timeout - so it seems like something must be locking / blocking my container from joining this network. How can I figure out what it is?

The swarm cluster is a dev cluster that consists of a single node, the issue appears intermittent but lasts many minutes when it happens. The docker version is 18.09.2 - if it matters?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the node to active:

```
docker node update --availability active MYNODE
```

and then try again

Comment: This is in a dev swarm cluster of one node. The behaviour is intermittent so I'll be sure to check - however I can't see any reason why the nodes would be going inactive. [Besides if I had a cluster of a sole inactive node I'm sure I'd have bigger problems! :o]

Comment: see https://success.docker.com/article/context-deadline-exceeded-error-observed-while-starting-container-on-drained-node

Comment: any chance of an update or a few more details or a repaired article link?
currently seeing this exact behaviour on 1/3 swarm managers after a reboot. The container restart policy is set to `always` but it never attempts a restart after encountering this error :( As soon as I connect to the machine I just need to run `docker start` on the bad container and all works well, so it seems to be something ungraceful about the reboot, so triggering the node availability command on reboot is probably not the correct solution (because its "available" literally 30 seconds later anyway)